# How can I get boto3 script to run as a Lambda function?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

This works from the CLI but not from within AWS Lambda:

```
#This will list out all volumes that aren't in use or attached to instances
import boto3
import sys

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
client = boto3.client('sns')
vol_array = ec2.volumes.all()
vol_avail = []

#def chk_vols(event, context):
for v in vol_array:
    if v.state == 'available':
        vol_avail.append(v.id)

response = client.publish(
    TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:444444444444:adm-group',
    Message=str(vol_avail),
    Subject='AWS Volumes Available'
)
```

I would like to convert this code to be an AWS Lambda function. I've uncommented the line:
    #def chk_vols(event, context):
And properly shifted the For loop over to be under the 'def' statement.

This code will check if any AWS volumes are in the available state and send an SNS message to the adm-group topic. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is your problem related to permissions or simply related to how to code and configure the Lambda function handler itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get my original code to work.

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
sns = boto3.client('sns')

def chk_vols(event, context):
    vol_array = ec2.volumes.all()
    vol_avail = []

    for v in vol_array:
        if v.state == 'available':
            vol_avail.append(v.id)

    if vol_avail:
        sns.publish(
            TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:444444444444:adm-group',
            Message=str(vol_avail),
            Subject='AWS Volumes Available'
        )
```

Thank you for your time and comments.

Comment: I know this was old but I was going crazy tonight because I put the resource method call inside of my lambda handler and it would not work, do you know why that fails but putting getting the resource outside of the handler works?

Answer (score 2):

For any resource access to AWS over any supported method require the request to be authenticated. If you have the AWS CLI configured locally, `boto3` knows how to use those credentials to authenticate and hence you're able to access resources and modify them.

Unfortunately, Lambda doesn't support credentials as you need to consider other ways. Most secure way is to use `STS` to assume a role and get temporary credentials.

```
    try:
        sts_client = boto3.client('sts')

        assumedRoleObject = sts_client.assume_role(
            RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::" + "AwsAccountNumber" + ":role/" + "RoleWithSTSPermissions",
            RoleSessionName="NameOfTheSession"
        )

        credentials = assumedRoleObject['Credentials']

        _client = boto3.client(
            'ec2',
            aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
            aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
            aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
            region_name=_region
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.message)
        raise
```

Its ideal if these things are variables so you can dynamically change them for the need.

> Example

```
import os
import boto3
import logging

AwsAccount = dict(
    number=None,
    role=None,
    region=None
)
def authenticate(_region, _resource):
    try:
        sts_client = boto3.client('sts')

        assumedRoleObject = sts_client.assume_role(
            RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::" + AwsAccount['number'] + ":role/" + AwsAccount['role'],
            RoleSessionName="LambdaAssumeRoleSession"
        )

        credentials = assumedRoleObject['Credentials']

        _client = boto3.client(
            _resource,
            aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
            aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
            aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
            region_name=_region
        )
    except Exception as e:
        log.warn(e.message)
        log.warn("Switching to local credentials")

        try:
            # TODO: Remove failover profile in production
            _session = boto3.session.Session(region_name=_region)
            _client = _session.client(_resource, region_name=_region)
            log.info("Successfully authenticated using local credentials")
        except Exception as e:
            log.error(e.message)
            raise

    return _client

def main():
    _client = authenticate(AwsAccount['region'], 'ec2')

    return

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        AwsAccount['number'] = os.environ['AWS_ACCOUNT'].strip()
        AwsAccount['region'] = os.environ['AWS_REGION'].strip()
        AwsAccount['role'] = os.environ['AWS_LAMBDA_ROLE'].strip()
    except Exception as e:
        log.error(e)
        raise

    main()

    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lambda_handler(None, None)
```

This code can be tested on your local and on Lambda give that you've configured the environment variable on both local & Lambda

When you creating the Lambda function, make sure to define the `lambda_handler` as the handler.

Comment: Lambda does support IAM permisions via IAM roles which can be assigned to the Lambda. While this suggestion is not bad security-wise, it is not accurate to say that IAM is not supported by Lambda.

Comment: @JamesG I wasn't saying Lambda didn't support IAM Role, I was saying it's doesn't support credentials like the CLI does. For my answer it does need role to work anyway. Sorry if I cause any confusion.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments and the code example. I successfully ran a Python  3.7 script from my command prompt (CLI). I do have the AWS CLI installed and configured using the credentials / config files, with profiles.

The IAM role that the Lambda function is using has the following permissions added to it:
AdministrativeAcess
AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
AmazonSNSFullAccess
I started with AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole and added others 'to test'.

Comment: This is working as intended, but I am working on determining the exact access that is needed.

`# This will list out all volumes that aren't in use or attached to instances
import boto3
import sys

def chk_vols(event, context):
 ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
 client = boto3.client('sns')
 vol_array = ec2.volumes.all()
 vol_avail = []
 for v in vol_array:
  if v.state == 'available':
   vol_avail.append(v.id)

 response = client.publish(
  TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:444444444444:ep-adm-grp',
  Message=str(vol_avail),
  Subject='AWS Volumes Available'
 )`

Comment: The easiest way that I found is to use the `Create policy` wizard in the `IAM`. It allows sandbox so you can test the policy in action. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html

Comment: From my understanding, the client created by `boto3` inside a lambda function takes on the IAM role assigned to the lambda function. Thus, as long as the permission is sufficient for the role assigned to the lambda function, the `boto3` client shall also have sufficient permission. One can always assign lambda the most lenient permission to check if it works. If it does, then we can gradually squeeze the permission tighter.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to associate an IAM Role with Lambda that has needed permissions. Reference docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/intro-permission-model.html#lambda-intro-execution-role

Comment: This answer is accurate, but good SO answers provide a little more detail than just a link. Could you elaborate on some of the steps required to attach an IAM role? I would do it but you deserve the accepted answer for this.